# How to prevent open layers DrawInteraction to draw LineString if the user clicks "wrong" area?

Tags: openlayers

When the polyline draw is started with a mouse singleclick, the 'drawstart' event is fired. Can I cancel/prevent the draw somehow if some condition prevents it?

```
const draw = new DrawInteraction({ type: geometryType });
draw.on('drawstart', (evt) => {
  // if some condition abort/prevent/cancel the whole thing
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It may not be the only solution but removing the interaction from the map will cancel any drawing in progress, then you add it back

```
draw.on('drawstart', function(e) {
  if (cancelcondition) {
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
    map.addInteraction(draw);
  }
});
```

It would be better to stop the draw starting by testing in the condition option for the draw (that could also be used to prevent a validly started drawing being extended into a no-go area)

```
import {noModifierKeys} from 'ol/events/condition';

const draw = new DrawInteraction({
  type: geometryType,
  condition: function(e) {
    return noModifierKeys(e) && !cancelcondition
  }
});
```